# Kubernetes: Trying to add second master node to K8S master using stacked control plane instructions

Tags: kubernetes

I was following instructions at https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/high-availability/#stacked-control-plane-and-etcd-nodes and I can't get the secondary master node to join the primary master.

```
$> kubeadm join LB_IP:6443 --token TOKEN --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash sha256:HASH --experimental-control-plane
[preflight] running pre-flight checks
[discovery] Trying to connect to API Server "LB_IP:6443"
[discovery] Created cluster-info discovery client, requesting info from "https://LB_IP:6443"
[discovery] Requesting info from "https://LB_IP:6443" again to validate TLS against the pinned public key
[discovery] Cluster info signature and contents are valid and TLS certificate validates against pinned roots, will use API Server "LB_IP:6443"
[discovery] Successfully established connection with API Server "LB_IP:6443"
[join] Reading configuration from the cluster...
[join] FYI: You can look at this config file with 'kubectl -n kube-system get cm kubeadm-config -oyaml'

One or more conditions for hosting a new control plane instance is not satisfied.

unable to add a new control plane instance on a cluster that doesn't use an external etcd

Please ensure that:
* The cluster has a stable controlPlaneEndpoint address.
* The cluster uses an external etcd.
* The certificates that must be shared among control plane instances are provided.
```

Here is my admin init config:

```
apiVersion: kubeadm.k8s.io/v1alpha3
kind: ClusterConfiguration
kubernetesVersion: "1.12.3"
apiServer:
  certSANs:
  - "LB_IP"
controlPlaneEndpoint: "LB_IP:6443"
networking:
  podSubnet: "192.168.128.0/17"
  serviceSubnet: "192.168.0.0/17"
```

And I initialized the primary master node like:

```
kubeadm init --config=./kube-adm-config.yaml
```

I have also copied all the certs to the secondary node and kubectl works on the secondary:

```
[root@secondary ~]# kubectl get nodes
NAME                            STATUS   ROLES    AGE   VERSION
primary.fqdn                    Ready    master   8h    v1.12.3
```

I was really hoping to not set up external etcd nodes. The instructions seem pretty straightforward and I don't understand what I am missing.

Any advice to help get this stacked control plane multi-master setup with local etcd to work would be appreciated. Or any debugging ideas. Or at least "stacked control plane doesn't work, you must use external etcd".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading to k8s version 1.13.0 resolved my issue. I think the instructions were specifically for this newer version.

Comment: Yes it is, your instruction for version 1.13

Answer (score 0):

Check your configmap for kubeadm to make sure control-plane endpoint exists. If not,add it.

```
kubectl -n kube-system edit cm kubeadm-config
```

```html
apiVersion: v1
data:
  ClusterConfiguration: |
    apiVersion: kubeadm.k8s.io/v1beta3
    certificatesDir: /etc/kubernetes/pki
    clusterName: kubernetes
    controlPlaneEndpoint: <IP/DNS>:6443
    ...
```